# Ping General Failure In Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have 2 computers connected via a TP-Link router on my LAN, a windows 7 ultimate 64bit and a windows 10 enterprise 64bit. On windows 7 I'm able to ping the wind windows 10 machine successfully but on the windows 10 I get an error "General Failure", even if I ping the gateway I still face the same error.

I need your help guys on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of had the same Issue. Couldn´t ping my own ip or my gateway. For me it was the nord-Vpn service running in the background. Once i shut it down in the taskmanager, i could successfully ping again. So maybe check if there are VPN-Services running.